# How to access the server of a computer in same network?

Tags: networking, windows-10, apache-http-server

I'm newbiw to network. I installed vertrigo on machine A at home and would like to access it from machine B. I thought I would just add a rule to allow access via 80 port on firewall, copy local IPV4 address then I would access it via browser on the machine B. But it can't find the server. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to use the public IP or private/LAN IP address of the server? If you your public IP, you need to investigate your hairpin NAT settings. If you use LAN, there is no need for any firewall rules and network probably isn't what is wrong here.

Comment: I'm using LAN, both machines are connected via Wi-Fi. Does it matter?

Comment: 1)Can you ping machine A IP? 2)can you telnet to machine A IP on port 80? 3)what is the specific error you get in your browser when you try to access the http server?

Comment: @MaQleod When I ping the IP Address I get the error `destination host unreachable` when I try to open the server in the browser I get `Request timed out` from Firefox.

Comment: If you can’t ping, nothing above the IP layer will work. Destination host unreachable is a routing error - your computer has no idea how to reach the server and neither does its gateway. If you’re on a LAN are you sure both machines are on the same subnet? What is the IP and subnet mask of both of them?

Comment: It seems the machine B can't see machine A but I have no idea why...They're both connected to same network.  Check the IP and Subnet: https://pastebin.com/raw/6zJjdXRE Is that how the values are supposed to be?

Comment: Yeah, that looks right. So for ping to work, an arp conversation must first complete, so something is likely going wrong there. Can both machines ping the gateway (they don’t need a gateway, but it is still a good test of first hop connectivity and to figure out which machine is having the issue)?

Comment: I give up on this approach. I just installed create a HotSpot from machine A then connected to thiis in the machine B then everything worked.